# Where to put scripts that run when computer is resumed?

Tags: arch-linux, suspend, pm-utils

I need to lock the screen when my computer is waken up from memory suspend,

So I tried to put the following script to `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d` and `/etc/pm/sleep.d`, but it never got executed,

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    hibernate|suspend)
        ;;
    thaw|resume)
        vlock -ans
        ;;
    *) exit $NA
        ;;
esac
```

P.S It's `pm-suspend` not `pm-hibernate`.

**EDIT**

Tried systemd service as well, no luck:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/resume@.service
[Unit]
Description=User resume actions
After=suspend.target

[Service]
User=root
Type=simple
ExecStart=vlock -ans

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
```

And I called `systemctl enable resume@.service` too, vlock wasn't called still.

Comment: Are you sure it will not get executed? Can you try to just log it or do something like `echo executed script >> /tmp/resume`

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK `ExecStart` wants a full path to the executable.

Try with `ExecStart=/usr/bin/vlock -ans` in your `/etc/systemd/system/resume@.service`

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the permissions and owner as [described in the wiki?](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pm-utils#Locking_the_screen_saver_on_hibernate_or_suspend)

> Make sure the script is executable (chmod 755) and owned by root:root

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to create your own hook, right?  I'm reading the Arch Linux documentation on pm-utils (link below) and I'd check these things first:

- script name (start with two digits, obeying the scheme in the docs)
- script location: /etc/pm/sleep.d is the right place
- script modes: chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/66scriptname

If you're sure you've got all those right, then consider the script itself.

Here's a link to the docs I'm reading about this:
    https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/pm-utils#Creating_your_own_hooks

Your script isn't quite like the one they show there.  You invoke /bin/sh instead of /bin/bash.  You use double-qoutes around $1 and they don't.  You combine options and they don't.  All of which *should* be OK, right?  Except maybe the sh versus bash.

How about putting some [logger](http://linux.die.net/man/1/logger) or echo statements in there for debugging and then check the logs to see if you script is getting started.  And if it is, how far it's getting.

Comment: Does systemd work with pm-utils? I'm not sure about that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I found out all the directories by doing a `"sudo strace pm-hibernate 2>/root/myfile.log"`, or you can replace the pm-hibernate with pm-suspend.   After sometime the machine will powerdown.   Then when you powerup / resume again, read the myfile.log, and within it are all the scripts, config, log files accessed/written.

For my Fedora 20 they are:

```
/usr/lib64/pm-utils/pm-functions
/usr/lib64/pm-utils/defaults
/usr/lib64/pm-utils/module.d
/etc/pm/config.d
/etc/pm/pm-suspend.config.d
/var/run/pm-utils/locks/pm-suspsnd.lock
/var/run/pm-utils/pm-suspend/storage/parameters
```

etc and several other directories.

Help yourself with your specific distro of specific version (Fedora 20 is using systemd btw).