# Lock system after awake suspend (incl. forced-shutdowns system after countdown)?

Tags: security, suspend, screen-lock

For speed and convenience I do not shutdown my system when I am only gone some minutes, but do a `pm-suspend`! When the system "unsuspends"/resumes I would like that there is a (screen)lock (on X and all other terminals) which in addition should initiate a forced shutdown after some time has passed without login.

- [Locking console when computer suspends/hibernates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/118384/locking-console-when-computer-suspends-hibernates)
- [Where to put scripts that run when computer is resumed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59471/where-to-put-scripts-that-run-when-computer-is-resumed?rq=1)

already indicate some way to me. And the special aspects sought in this question is that of:

- BOTH all virtual terminals this (tty1-tty6) should be inaccessible
- AND X should be inaccessible
- MOREOVER I would like that after resume/wakeup there is only a brief time slot to login again and else the system should "self-destruct"

An important reason/backgroud is that I do want to limit risk to expose an unlocked LUKS partition. While upon boot the disk is protected but not when I leave my system only suspended.

Answer (score 1):

This `sleep.d` script should work (replace `<youruser>` with a user you've got the password for. I ran it with root the first time and couldn't get back in):

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    hibernate|suspend)
       ;;
    thaw|resume)
       USER=<youruser> /usr/bin/vlock -ans &
       echo $! > /var/run/vlock.pid
       /opt/bin/timeout_vlock.sh &
       ;;
    *) exit $NA
       ;;
esac
```

The content of `/opt/bin/timeout_vlock.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMEOUT=10

while kill -0 $(< /var/run/vlock.pid); do
    [ $TIMEOUT -le 0 ] && break
    sleep 1
    let TIMEOUT--
done

rm /var/run/vlock.pid
[ $TIMEOUT -le 0 ] && shutdown -h now
```

Adjust `TIMEOUT` to the desired value and make sure you give it execution permission: `chmod +x /opt/bin/timeout_vlock.sh'.

The `sleep.d` script uses vlock to lock all ttys (even the one with X), disable sysrq and prompt for your user password to unlock. It saves vlock's pid for later use.

The `timeout_vlock.sh` waits for vlock to finish (which happens when you input your password). If TIMEOUT is reached, it shutdowns the system.

Comment: The script only works on bash, sorry about that. I will make it portable if it turns out to be useful for someone.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! Is the script working independent of the `init` system?

Comment: The solution works almost perfect, yet I want to mention this. `vlock` (as I looked it up in the source, version 2.2.2) tries hard to disable vt switching `chvt` yet the `pm-suspend` (in the version of `pm-utils`  1.4.1-9fix.ubuntu12.04) when reawaking allows for about 1-2 seconds (on my system) to change to X via `Alt-Crtl-F7`. For security's sake one should test if `pm-suspend` screws up the vt-switch-prevention attampted by `vlock`.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is building on the answer suggested from  @gnp. The difference being that to reduce the risk of `vlock` locking of virtual console/terminal switching being impacted by the usual `pm-suspend` etc hacks that tinker with the consoles.

Similar the answer of @gnp we need two files

`/etc/pm/sleep.d/20_lock_with_countdown` (with +x file permission)

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
    hibernate|suspend)

       # generate a kernel/console keymap that has no Console_1 .... Console7
       # and no Incr_Console and no Decr_Console keymappings
       dumpkeys -f |\
       tee /tmp/oldkeymap |\
       sed 's/Console_[0-9]*/VoidSymbol/g' |\
       sed 's/Incr_Console/VoidSymbol/g' |\
       sed 's/Decr_Console/VoidSymbol/g' > /tmp/keymap.with.chvtkeys.disabled

       #set the new "castrated" keymap
       loadkeys /tmp/keymap.with.chvtkeys.disabled
       ;;
    thaw|resume)
       USER=<username> /usr/bin/vlock -ans &
       echo $! > /var/run/vlock.pid
       /opt/bin/timeout_vlock.sh &
       ;;
    *) exit $NA
       ;;
esac
```

and then a script for the countdown unlock
`/opt/bin/timeout_vlock.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

TIMEOUT=<timeout>

while kill -0 $(< /var/run/vlock.pid); do
    [ $TIMEOUT -le 0 ] && break
    sleep 1
    let TIMEOUT--
done

rm /var/run/vlock.pid
# restore keymap with previous "chvt enabled" keys enabled
loadkeys /tmp/oldkeymap
[ $TIMEOUT -le 0 ] && shutdown -h now
```

As in the other answer the field `<timeout>` and `<username>` should be adjusted in the scripts.

Last but not least it is possible to switch the last line of
`/opt/bin/timeout_vlock.sh`

```
< [ $TIMEOUT -le 0 ] && shutdown -h now
----
> [ $TIMEOUT -le 0 ] &&  echo u > /proc/sysrq-trigger `
> [ $TIMEOUT -le 0 ] &&  echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

`

to avoid another short interaction window of malicious oportunity, as not always is `shutdown -h now` the [fastest way to poweroff your PC](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/163370/24394)

Comment: I belive it should be `echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger`. Also, that is not a very safe way of shutting down... You should at least `echo u > /proc/sysrq-trigger` first to protect uncommited data. I would add `e`, `i` and `s` just to be sure. It doesn't add much delay to the shutdown process.

Comment: @gnp thank you for pointing to that mistake, so I could correct it.

Comment: You're welcome. Does it work correctly? I just remembered that `vlock -s` disables sysrq rendering this shutdown approach impractical...