# Is there a fastest way to shutdown the system?

Tags: performance, shutdown

Or is `shutdown -h now` the fastest it can get?

I look for some syscall or similar that will allow to skip lots of the stuff done prior to shutdown (in particular to care about the running proccesses).

At best I would like a kernel related solution, being ignorant to the `init`-middleware (like `systemd` or `upstart`).

The risks related with i.e. killing directly all services like cups/apache/pulseaudio etc... I would not care....

remark:
the solution should be software-vice. Pressing buttons at the device is not what I look for.

Comment: *"The risks related with i.e. killing directly all services like cups/apache/pulseaudio etc... I would not care...."* -> Are you sure? Leaving complex software in an inconsistent state may lead to nasty surprises next time it is used.  Maybe you should consider disabling services you don't use much (e.g. cups, apache); you can always start and stop those things manually when you do want to use them.

Comment: The method I seek is for the moment in which I want to avoid people having access to my PC. Any delay in shutting down allows mischieve. I rather loose data then expose it.

Comment: Also visit [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/491146)

Comment: [There's an idea.](https://www.doit.wisc.edu/assets/unplug.jpg) Start saving money for some new hardware though.

Comment: `sudo shutdown -P 0`  I use that and it starts the shutdown process right away, no matter what apps are open

Comment: @humanityANDpeace what people do you mean? If the people are trying to access the machine over the network, then you do not actually have to shutdown the machine - shutting down the network should be enough.  If the people have physical access to the machine, then again shutting down the machine is not necessary (or even sufficient) - you need to ensure that sensitive information is in an encrypted state.

Comment: @emroy without being being to precise I meant mostly persons with direct physical access. The *as fast as possible shutdown* has the goal to keep the hdd encryption safe, which it would less when the machine would shutdown slower and i.e. interrupted its shutdown.

Comment: Is this question Linux-specific? Please tag accordingly.

Comment: [What's the fastest way to kill a server?](http://serverfault.com/q/160526) on Server Fault

Comment: @humanityANDpeace I would guess that the answer is to store all sensitive data on an encrypted partition.  Closing that partition has to be faster than shutting down the machine.

Comment: @emory I am not sure about that. the hardreset/hardshutdown is virtually instantanous, while I think the kernel might spend up to a second figuring out about still accessing executable. Also the RAM with all caching etc. I do backups, so I can better life with potential loss than with a disclosure or worse compromitation.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It doesn't get much faster than using the System Request (SysRq) functionality and then triggering an immediate `reboot`.

This is a key combination understood by the kernel.

Enable SysRq:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
```

Now, send it into reboot.

```
echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

`b` - Immediately reboot the system, without unmounting or syncing filesystems.

**Note:**

Although this is a `reboot` it will behave like the power has been cut off, which is not recommended.

If you want to `sync` and `umount` the filesystems before hand then use:

```
echo s > /proc/sysrq-trigger
echo u > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

or if you just want to power off the system then:

```
echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

---

**Magic key combinations**

There are also key combinations to use that are interpreted by the kernel:

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq / Print Screen</kbd>+<kbd>Command Key</kbd>

*Command Keys:*

<kbd>R</kbd> - Take control of keyboard back from X.
<kbd>E</kbd> - Send SIGTERM to all processes, allowing them to terminate gracefully.
<kbd>I</kbd> - Send SIGKILL to all processes, forcing them to terminate immediately.
<kbd>S</kbd> - Flush data to disk.
<kbd>U</kbd> - Remount all filesystems read-only.
<kbd>B</kbd> - Reboot.

*Quoting from the [Magic SysRq Key Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key):*

> A common use of the magic SysRq key is to perform a safe reboot of a Linux computer which has otherwise locked up.
>
> 1. Hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>SysRq</kbd> (Print Screen) keys.
> 2. While holding those down, type the following keys in order, several seconds apart: **REISUB**.
> 3. Computer should reboot.

A way to remember these are:

> "**R**eboot **E**ven **I**f **S**ystem **U**tterly **B**roken" or simply the word "**BUSIER**" read backwards.

**References**

[Magic SysRq Key Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)
[Fedora SysRq](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/QA/Sysrq)

Comment: It's important to note that a clean system can take even less than 2 seconds to shutdown. When I call `poweroff` on my Arch machine, I can't even see the shutdown log being printed on screen...

Comment: Before the second echo, you would want to run `sync` (http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_sync.htm), which would make sure that buffers are written to the disk, including superblocks.

Comment: you suggest the `b` being echod not `o`. Is b better?

Comment: It depends what you mean by better. While the `b` option is very fast, it does not `sync` the disks, which is not ideal, there are many options which provide ways of cutting down on the shutdown time, some more extreme than others. There is also a `panic` option. Read the wiki and trial and error to see what best meets your needs.

Comment: Well on my screwed-up system the `echo o /proc/sysrq-trigger` does create a hang. The system stays on. Indeed the `b` the system is gone. Yet it reboots that means that the RAM can be kept, which is a vulnerability I would like the `b` option with the system being off in the end. Sadly this does not work with `o` option in my sys. Thanks for the suggestion to you and also to @Pandya

Comment: You should also mention the mnemonic/acronym/whatever "REISUB" which is used for "panic shutdowns"/

Comment: @hexafraction - good call, will get it done.

Comment: You shouldn't sync using the sysrq command, as it doesn't wait for the sync to finish. Simple `sync` would grant the clean buffer.

Answer (score 9):

The nasty approach is `shutdown -h -n now`.

Note that this will not do any cleanup, so file systems may get inconsistent, databases break etc., but it shuts down the system really fast.

Comment: thank you, this sounds interessting: is this `-n` option documented and still in current version of shutdown?

Comment: Yes, that is standard. It directly tells the kernel to drop everything. This command is normally used from the last shutdown script, when the regular shutdown has completed.

Comment: But I cannot stress enough that this will most likely cause bad effects, as it is largely equivalent to pulling the plug.

Comment: Wonderfully simple and effective. This -n option is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you SO MUCH for answering the question as-asked. You don't know how frustrating it is to ask a question and hear the neckbeards all tell you why your question is wrong instead of just answering it. I would upvote this answer fifty times if I could. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 5):

Some distros offer a `poweroff` command which is simpler than `shutdown`.

Using it with:

```
poweroff -f
```

will perform a disk sync and then power down. This is a good compromise between being much faster while still performing the minimal shutdown to ensure the filesystems are not corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the init command:

```
init 0
```