# Panic/reboot multiple servers simultaneously via Ansible

Tags: ansible, panic

I want to panic/reboot multiple servers at the same time via Ansible CLI, however, the command below gets stuck at execution. Could someone advise how to revise the command to achieve the concurrent panic/reboot?

```
ansible HostGroup -m shell -a 'echo b >/proc/sysrq-trigger'
```

Comment: Too sleep deprived to make a full post, but maybe the [reboot builtin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/reboot_module.html) is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

Rule #1 of Ansible: See if there's already a module that covers a use case before you fall back to shell commands.

In this case, there is in fact a [reboot](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/reboot_module.html) module.

As per the examples on that page, you'd want a playbook roughly like this:

```yaml
---
hosts: HostGroup
tasks:
  - name: Reboot systems
    ansible.builtin.reboot:
```

Alternately, if you're doing it from the command line, `ansible -m reboot HostGroup` should do the trick.

As always with Ansible, test the command out on a system you can afford to screw up before you do it to any production server.

Comment: unstood, but I need to panic the mulitple server with command line, but it usually stucked on the 1st server

Comment: I'm almost *positive* that you don't need that. What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? It's starting to sound like we're having an XY problem here.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are somehow similar question and answers regarding the mentioned command

- [Difference between `reboot -n` and `echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger`?](https://serverfault.com/a/622660/448950)
- [What's the difference between `echo 'b' >> /proc/sysrq-trigger` and `reboot`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37651204/6771046)

I understand that you are looking for a task which immediately reboot all systems without flushing, syncing or unmounting disks, as well closing all network connections, like in

- [Is there a fastest way to shutdown the system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163372/266568)
- [Remotely shutting down the system (restarting) and instant booting](https://superuser.com/questions/349034/)

Please take note that Ansible isn't a kind of cluster shell or terminal multiplexer and even the ad-hoc command do not behave like that.

Therefore your current approach as it is will not provide the expected result for you.

This is because the devices which Ansible are connects to are going to restart faster than Ansible and the `shell` module can maintain his own status and connection. Meaning, close and disconnect the sessions. Similar behavior can be found in example in [Reload ... Devices Hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75092918/6771046).

You are probably looking for [Asynchronous ad hoc tasks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html#asynchronous-ad-hoc-tasks) which acts in a kind of "*fire and forget*" manner and end up with something like

```bash
ansible HostGroup --background 5 --poll 0 --module-name shell --args 'echo b >/proc/sysrq-trigger'
```

**Documentation**

- [Run tasks concurrently: poll = 0](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_async.html#run-tasks-concurrently-poll-0)

  > *If you want to run multiple tasks in a playbook concurrently, use `async` with `poll` set to 0. When you set `poll: 0`, Ansible starts the task and immediately moves on to the next task without waiting for a result.*

**Similar Q&A**

- [Ansible ad-hoc command background not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47108814/6771046)

**Some more references**

- [Fast system shutdown in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46249369/6771046)

Comment: this works for me, 3x